# Upgrading to API 22 breaks test suite

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I am attempting to upgrade an existing project to compile with and target API 22. I changed the following lines in my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
...

    defaultConfig {
...
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
...
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
...
    }
}
```

Note that these are the **only** changes in the **entire** project. Now suddenly, many of my tests fail. All of the failing tests use Robotium and call `solo.clickOnActionBarItem()`. However, the button on the action bar never seems to be clicked. When I watch the test running, I do not see the expected behavior from the button click.

What are the reasons for the failure of `solo.clickOnActionBarItem()` to not click an action bar item? More importantly, how can I figure out what the problem is when it appears to be something in a third-party library I am using?

Comment: Does the app work when you use it manually? In that case, my guess is that the algorithm that Robotium used to find the widgets associated with action bar items broke. That's one of the downsides with tools that rely on internal implementation instead of APIs (unavoidable in this case, but still).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, the app works manually.

Comment: @CommonsWare Robotium's algorithm appears to be quite simple: [it calls `Instrumentation.invokeMenuActionSync()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.android.robotium/robotium-solo/5.2.1/com/robotium/solo/Clicker.java#Clicker.clickOnActionBarItem%28int%29).

Comment: `Instrumentation` won't necessarily know about `appcompat-v7`, though, any more than it might know about ActionBarSherlock or any other action bar backport. I would presume that requires the library to be specifically designed to adhere to what `Instrumentation` expects. Perhaps `appcompat-v7:22` changed things around enough to cause `invokeMenuActionSync()` to not find the menu item.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your help. This might be the reason for me to look more closely at Espresso or other mechanisms to do the same thing that my current tests do under earlier versions of the Android API.